# Issues with Google Earth Engine Python API - "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inet_pton'"

Tags: python, python-2.7, gis, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to use Google Earth Engine via the Python API. I used pip to install (pip install earthengine-api) and when I run pip list earthengine-api shows up.

However, I'm trying to go through the [Python Installation Guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install) and when I tried to run the Initialization sequence:

```
import ee 
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```

It works up to a point. I am able to get and enter the verification code, but running the cell fails with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inet_pton'
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this error and how to fix it?